# Cannot import module file in node js

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, express-validator

I have written module for common uses.

```
const { check, body } = require('express-validator/check');
var models = require("../models");

let Validations = [
    check('email').isEmail().withMessage("Invalid Email"),
    check('phone').isLength({ min: 5 }).withMessage("Min length Required"),
    check('name').not().isEmpty().withMessage("Value is Required"),
    body("name").custom(value => {
        return models.fundraisers.findByName(value).then(user => {
        if (user) {
            return Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');
        }
        })
    })
]

export { Validations };
```

I am trying to access like below.

```
import Validations from "../validations/fundraiser";
```

But I am getting the below error.

```
import Validations from "../validations/fundraiser";
       ^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifierI
```

I couldn't find what is the problem. Please help anyone to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try - import { Validations} from "../validations/fundraiser"; Also please check you nodeJs version if it supports es6 syntax or not

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Already I tried this. Not working Bro. NodeJs Version is v10.12.0

Answer (score 1):

imports are still experimental feature in node.js.

to use them you should use `--experimental-modules` running node, and use `*.mjs` extension

`node --experimental-modules test.mjs`

test.mjs:

```
import a from './test2'
a();
```

test2.mjs:

```
const a = () => console.log(22)
export default a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up `commonjs` modules with `ES6` modules. You can read more about the basics [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/). What you can do is change:

```
export { Validations };
```

to

```
module.exports = Validations;
```

then when you import it use the following syntax:

```
const Validations = require('../validations/fundraiser');
```

If you want to use the newer syntax, then

1. be consistent and use `import` / `export`
2. use a transpiler like [`babel`](https://babeljs.io/) to transform your code to `commonjs` syntax so you can also use it in node and older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
const  Validations = [...];

...

export default Validations;
```

and then:

```
import Validations from '../validations/fundraiser';
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try to import like this mate

import { Validations } from "../validations/fundraiser";

and also to do this your node should support ES6 and above .. cheers mate

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Already I tried this and not working. Nodejs version is v10.12.0

Answer (score 0):

like @axm_ answer:

Here a example:

file: functions.js

```
 const API = {

}

API.sayHello = () => {
  return console.log('Hello')
}

API.sayGoodbye = () => {
  return console.log('good bye!')
}

API.doSomeThing = () => {
  return console.log('let do some thing!')
}

module.exports = API
```

File index.js

```
const API = require('./functions')

API.sayHello()
API.doSomeThing()
API.sayGoodbye()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to default exports
you can't import stuff without curly braces, unless the object being exported is the default export

```js
import { foo } from './example';
```

if you don't wanna use the curly braces you can export foo as the default export

```js
export default foo;
```

then you can use

```js
import foo from "./example";
```